# Angular 2 router not loading on refresh until I click button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am making a tabbed dashboard and am using angular 2 router v.3.0.0-beta.1 and am having issues loading the app initially. Whenever I load the page I have to click a tab in order for /dashboards in  to actually appear. At first I thought it had to do with my route link (currently commented out) in tab 1, but it still happens without it. I am trying to have tab 1 autodisplay and then have each tab contain its own route. The other tabs dont seem to be working either in terms of containing different routes or print functions. Any help would be appreciated.
 app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [
    MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES,
    MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES,
    MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,
    MdToolbar,
    MdButton,
    MdInput,
    MdCheckbox,
    MdRadioGroup,
    MdRadioButton,
    MdIcon,
    MD_TABS_DIRECTIVES,
    DashboardsComponent,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
  ],
  providers: [MdIconRegistry, MdRadioDispatcher, DashboardService],
  precompile: [DashboardsComponent]


})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  dashboards: Dashboard[];
  selectedDashboard: Dashboard;
  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService,
              private router: Router) { console.log("outer constr");}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("outer init");

  }

  print() {console.log("TRYING");}


}
```

app.routes.ts

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardsComponent
  }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

app.component.html

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav mode="push"#sidenav>
   <!-- <md-nav-list>
      <a md-list-item *ngFor="let view of views">
       <md-icon md-list-icon>{{view.icon}}</md-icon>
       <span md-line>{{view.name}}</span>
       <span md-line class="secondary">{{view.description}}</span>
      </a>
    </md-nav-list>-->
  </md-sidenav>
  <md-toolbar color="primary">

<!--button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.open()"">
<md-icon>menu</md-icon>
</button-->
Braavos
</md-toolbar>
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>One</template>
    <nav>
    <!--a routerLink="/dashboards" routerLinkActive="active">One</a-->
  </nav>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab (click)="print()">
    <template md-tab-label>Two</template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab (click)="print()">
    <template md-tab-label>Three</template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Four</template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Five</template>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
</md-sidenav-layout>

<!--THIS IS WHERE ALL ROUTING APPEARS-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

dashboards.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboards',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'dashboards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../app.component.css'],
  directives: [
    MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES,
    MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,
    MdButton,
    MdInput,
    MdCheckbox,
    MdRadioGroup,
    MdRadioButton,
    MdIcon,
  ],
  providers: [MdIconRegistry, MdRadioDispatcher],

})
export class DashboardsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  dashboards: Dashboard[];
  selectedDashboard: Dashboard;
  private sub: any;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: DashboardService) {
      this.service.getDashboards(1).then(dashboard => this.dashboards = dashboard);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     });
    console.log("init");
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
    onSelect(dashboard: Dashboard) { this.selectedDashboard = dashboard; console.log(this.selectedDashboard.name); }

  //gotoDashboards() { this.router.navigate(['/dashboards']); }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend trimming down the amount of code you are including in your question - people are more likely to post answers if they are able to immediately see the troublesome code.

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is, what code should I trim? I included relevant files as this bug could be in any of them or even be a bug in angular 2

Comment: There isn't a single line of code you'd be confident removing from the post? You've posted your current code, which is good.. but with this amount of code, and no easy way to test, you're asking a lot of someone browsing here that might be able to answer.

Comment: And another benefit of trying to trimming your code is that you may find your own 'ah-ha' moment during the process when removing one line of code suddenly makes it works again.

Comment: Do you have `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: A Plunker that allows to reproduce would be helpful.

Comment: I do have href = "/" in the head tag.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your `index.html` file, but I suspect you may be including the `system-polyfills.js` script in your head. Removing this file solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your routes:

```
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard'
  },
```